# my background image shrink in header as display gets smaller

Tags: html, css

my question is that my background image shrink in header as display gets smaller, i want my image to fill (not stretch) my whole header.

[image]

[image]

as you can see in both the image that my code works perfect until i decrease my browser size till the size of mobile phone ,my image start shrink

[image]

i want my image to cover (fill not stretch) the whole header

[image]

here is my code:-

html:-

```
  <header>
        <img src="images/index/header/header.jpg">
  </header>
```

css:-

```
header {
    width:100%; 
    height:320px; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-1;
    border:1px solid lightgreen;
    object-fit: fill;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;


}

header img {
    width:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: use min-width:100% instead of width in img

Comment: he don't have issue of width

Comment: yes i have the issue of height

Comment: i also tried object-fit: cover;

Comment: use min-height in your image

Comment: why use an `img` tag at all ... try to set the background image of `header` to this image and set `background-size: cover`

Comment: just add `height:100%` in 'header img' css I think it will solve your height problem.

Comment: put your image inside div and set div min-width and min-height to 100%

Comment: @Vishwa this will stretch the image when the proportions are not met ... this is not what he wanted

Comment: @MichelEngelen Then he can use bootstrap with *img-responsive* class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position:absolute and height:100% in image tag like:-

```
header img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also you can use image in background instead of header.

```
header {
    width:100%; 
    height:320px; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-1;
    border:1px solid lightgreen;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("images/index/header/header.jpg");
    background-size: cover;


}
```

Comment: @arp123 i have added 320px, you can add more according to you.. Try this will definetely work

Comment: i am getting the same result

Comment: @arp123 , i have updated code,try that onece, position absolute and height:100%

Comment: i tried your updated code but it still didn't worked

Comment: @arp123 , i have used your code in jsfiddle, even m not getting any issue in that also. you can try background image instead... or just share the code snippet so that i can check there

Comment: i change the url location to http://.......jpg it works like a charm but image is not display when i add this location "images/index/header/header.jpg" (image location is correct, their is no spelling mistake)

Comment: Why did you accept the answer when it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the `img` tag out of this. It is not needed.

You should just set the `background-image` of header and then set `background-size: cover`. This wil fill your header container with the desired image.

```
header {
  width:100%;
  height:320px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:-1;
  border:1px solid lightgreen;
  background-image: url("images/index/header/header.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
}
```

---

Here is the working codepen example: https://codepen.io/michelengelen/pen/LQzmjE

Comment: @Michel_Engelen i tried your code but now image is not showing in header

Comment: Maybe you did pass in the wrong path? I did take what you wrote there. I will add a working codepen example to my answer

Comment: @Michel_Engelen i change the url location to http://.......jpg it works like a charm but image is not display when i add this location "images/index/header/header.jpg" (image location is correct, their is no spelling mistake)

Comment: where does you css lie ... check the folder structure ... the file path should be relative to the file that is referencing it

Answer (score 1):

use background image using css instead of img tag in html.

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
  background: url("images/index/header/header.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I proposed :D

Comment: Yes but there may not be any requirement of position or z-index which you have proposed..correct me if i am wrong. @MichelEngelen

Comment: depending on the situation it is needed for the flow of the site ... it is just the definition he posted here asking his question, so why should I alter anything besides the part that is relevant to the question?